# Java string - UTF and byte representation

Tags: java, string, encoding

I am wondering about java String and byte representation of it. I have a file encoded in UTF-16 little endian, when I view it in my hexeditor I can see

```
ff fe 61 00 f3 00 61 00 00
```

now, when I load it to Java using

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName),"UTF-16"));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        builder.append(line);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(builder.toString().getBytes()));
```

I can see in output

```
[97, -13, 97]
```

if I am printing bytes why can't I see the zero ones that I can see in my hexeditor?

Comment: What is the o/p of `builder.toString().getBytes("UTF-16LE")` ?

Comment: Now I can see the zeros correctly. EDIT: If i specify LE or BE I can see them correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because Java does not keeps the string in the UTF-16 format in memory, that would be wasteful, and because getBytes returns the string in the default system charset (which is probably not UTF-16 on your machine) [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) . The proper overload would be getBytes("UTF-16") - this way you should see the 0 padding at the end and maybe the BOM (ff fe) in the beginning.

Comment: I started to suspect that, now I am working on windows platform, so it makes sense now.